# Understanding save callbacks in rails: database row insert rolling back from failure that should come afterward

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've inherited a Rails app with an issue: user creation is rolled back if the welcome email fails to send. (But we always want the user to be created).

The *create* method calls *new* then *save*, and the email step is called in *after_create*, so an email issue shouldn't affect the save, right? 
But according to the stack trace, we fail at:

- *send_email* method (*deliver_now* line). That method was called by:
- *create* method in users_controller (the *if @user.save* line)

Note: the only place in the code that *send_email* is called is in the user.rb:

`after_create :send_email`

And of course we expect the transaction to roll back if any of the 'before' callbacks return false, but there are just two, that just update the object data and seem unrelated to email send:

```
  before_save :combine_dates
  before_save :set_timestamps
```

See below for the two methods that fail, followed by the two 'before' methods, that seem unrelated. Interestingly, when I break email so it won't send, we don't log either of those logger.error lines in CAPS- does that mean that @user.save is failing in a way we don't recover from?

Here's the create method:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params_with_races)

    existing_user = User.find_by_email(@user.email)
    if existing_user
        @user.is_dupe = true
    end

    if @user.save
      Rails.logger.error "USER.SAVE WAS TRUE"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do 
          if @user.contact?
            redirect_to mailing_list_user_path(@user)
            return
          end
          redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), notice: 'User was successfully created.'
        end
        format.js do 
          if @user.contact?
            render json: {redirect: mailing_list_user_path(@user)}
          else
            render json: {action: user_path(@user), email: @user.email}  
          end
        end
      end      

    else
      Rails.logger.error "USER.SAVE WAS FALSE"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js { head :not_acceptable }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is send_email:

```
  def send_email
    UserMailer.mailing_list(self).deliver_now if contact?
    UserMailer.welcome(self).deliver_now if diagnosed?
  end
```

Here are the two 'before' methods:

```
  def set_timestamps
    if email == email_confirmation and registered_at.blank?
      self.registered_at = Time.new
    end
  end

  def combine_dates
    if birthday_year_year.present? && birthday_day.present? && birthday_month.present?
      begin
        self.send('birthday=', Date.new(birthday_year_year.to_i, birthday_month.to_i, birthday_day.to_i))
      rescue
        self.send('birthday=', nil)
      end
    end
    if bd_birthday_year.present? && bd_birthday_day.present? && bd_birthday_month.present?
      begin
        self.send('bd_birthday=', Date.new(bd_birthday_year.to_i, bd_birthday_month.to_i, bd_birthday_day.to_i))
      rescue
        self.send('bd_birthday=', nil)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: IMO, using a callback to send an email is a bit smelly. It violates the separation of concerns which results in, well, exactly what your experiencing (you don't want your `@user.save` to be tangled up with `send_email`, but it is given your implementation). Perhaps you should consider using a service for sending your email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return false or have an exception in `before_save` or if you have an exception in `after_save` the transaction is rolled back and nothing is saved.

One way to manage this is (if you always want to send even if email fails) is to trap the exception within the method using `rescue`...

But even better, use after_commit instead of after_save

```
after_commit :send_email
```

Which exists exactly for this reason.

Comment: Thanks, @steveturczyn- that's the thing that's so strange: the code is using 'after_create' (not after_save), and the same is true if I update it to after_commit. I hadn't included the two before_save methods because they're just updating data on the object, but I've updated them now in case I'm missing something there.

Comment: update: it's still unclear why an after_create or after_commit exception would interfere with creation, but it was true that the email function didn't rescue exceptions! I've added that rescue statement now (and some logging), and now users are still created when the email system is down. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. `after_save` is called [before transaction is committed](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object) so if an exception is raised there, a record is not saved to DB.
2. Callback in Rails are synchronous by default, so if one of them raises unhandled exception, the "main flow" is interrupted and `#save` raises error.
3. As @jvillian mentioned in a comment - it's a bad idea to send emails from ActiveRercord callbacks.